# How to store cloned form values in array

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I need help figuring out how to keep all the values of the form fields from a cloned portion of my form. I clone only a div within the form, so that it's all within one form. When I enter multiple values (after clicking "Another"), I always get the last set of values I entered (which is expected, I know). But how can I submit the POST data to have all of the form values I entered?

Example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p><label>First Name</label><input type='text' name='first_name' value='' required></p><br>
<p><label>Last Name</label><input type='text' name='last_name' value='' required></p><br>
<h3>Additional Registration</h3>
<div id="reg_main">
    <div id="addition_reg">
        <div id="addition_reg_block">
            <p><label>Friend First Name</label><input type='text' name='friend_first_name' value=''></p><br>
            <p><label>Friend Last Name</label><input type='text' name='friend_last_name' value=''></p><br>
            <p><label>Friend Relation</label><input type='text' name='friend_relation' value=''></p>
            <input id="multi-friend" type="checkbox" name="more_friends" value="Multiple Friends" onclick="additional_friend()"> Another<br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p><br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function additional_friend() {
  var checked = document.getElementById("multi-friend").checked;
  if(checked == true){
    var clone = $("#addition_reg").clone("#addition_reg_block");
    $("#reg_main").append(clone);
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: clone() doesn't take a selector as argument and you will need to adjust `name`s. Can use array type names by adding `[]` to each one

Comment: You also can't repeat IDs in a page....they are unique by definition